# What can I do in Mapbox Studio with the osm_id number for #buildings from Mapbox Streets?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, streets, generate-tiles

My goal is to use OpenStreetMap buildings data to create map tiles that show buildings styled with information such as name, floors, and other information from the tags associated with the way/feature in the OSM database.

Is it possible to access the name of a `#building` through the `osm_id` in Mapbox Streets or by some other method?

What is the potential use of the `osm_id` in Mapbox Studio?

The specific use case here is a college campus map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the types of tags associated with a feature can be arbitrary and range in size, the `mapbox-streets-v5` source can only included a small subset of possible OSM tags for each feature they include.

For the `#building` layer, they have only included `osm_id`, but it shouldn't be hard to look up the building in osm (or just visually identify it) and add the name manually via Carto.

Because of the way MapBox Studio handles labels, you will need to apply the name label to the `#housenum_label` point layer, rather than the `#building` polygon layer (otherwise, the label might get repeated in strange ways on buildings that exist in multiple tiles.  [see this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/styling-labels/)

```
#housenum_label {
  [osm_id = xxx],[osm_id = yyy]{
    [osm_id = xxx]{ text-name = 'Name1'}
    [osm_id = yyy]{ text-name = 'Name2'}
    text-face-name: 'Open Sans Condensed Bold';
    text-size: 16;
  }
}
```

*Alternatively*, if the buildings are included in the `#poi_label` layer, the feature will already have a `name` field associated with it and you won't have to manually match `osm_id` to `name`.